# Android check if onStop is a result of Intent or the App entering background

Tags: android

Hi I am creating an app and I want to set user session in `onStop(`). For Example if a user pressed the home `button` and the app goes into background I want it to set session to false and when the user returns the `onResume()` will check if a user session is false or true then do something.

The problem I am having is `onStop()` is also called when an `intent` to another activity is called so when I return to that activity it thinks its false. I only want it to be false when the app is in the background.

Answer (score 1):

> intent to another activity is called

I suppose you mean you are calling this intent from your activity? You can always set some special flag in your activity when you are calling startActivity, also you can use startActivityForResult and onActivityResult, to findout what activity just finished.